# Javascript reset using button name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons on a page that I can't change code:

```
<button type="submit" name="next" class="button">Next</button>
<button type="submit" name="back" class="button">Previous</button>
```

On the back button I want to use javascript to reset the values of fields on that page by using:

```
document.getElementById(setV).value = "0"
```

I need to know how to do this on the name of a button.

I can't use getElementById or class as the name is the only thing to distinguish them. I have tried the follwing to take action but no joy:

```
$('[name="next"]').onclick();
```

Comment: I confused about what the question is?

Comment: is this what you want `$('[name="next"]').click(function(){$(this).val()})`

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('button')[1].click()`. Or you nearly got it `$('button[name="next"]').click();`.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs He said he cannot change the `HTML`.

Comment: @AjAX. Why not `querySelector('[name="next"]')`?

Comment: @AjAX. my bad didn't see :)

Comment: `<input type='reset'>`?

Comment: @LarsBeck **Selectors allow the representation of an element’s attributes. When a selector is used as an expression to match against an element, attribute selectors must be considered to match an element if that element has an attribute that matches the attribute represented by the attribute selector.** https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors. So you want to set an element first. Although **Nagarjun Prasad** solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

> `<input type="reset" value="Reset">`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using javascript:**

```
var backButton = document.querySelector("[name='back']")
backButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
 document.getElementById(setV).value = "0"
 // your code
}, false);
```

**2. Using jQuery:**

```
$(":button[name='back']").click(function(){
  document.getElementById(setV).value = "0"
  // your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on("click","button[name='next']",function(){
   $("#setV").val(0);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var backButton = document.querySelector("[name='back']")
```

to get the element with the name attribute. Then to change the value add a listener to the backButton element by:

```
backButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById('setV').value = '0';
});
```